# I'm having a problem updating state from a listener call back

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, getstream-io

i'm adding a chat feature to our site using GetStream's chat.  I'm trying to create a count badge on a button similar to FB, Twitter, IG, etc that displays the total of unread messages.   GetStream has an event listener to support this.  It's working, but it's not consistent.  If a user gets a new message, it shows the new badge and count.  But, if I navigate to any view other than the chat window, my count goes away.  If I hit refresh, it comes back.  Then... if I navigate around, it stays.   However, if I get a 2nd message, the count updates to 2, but if I navigate around, it's still at 1 until I refresh, and then it shows 2.  Also, it should reset to 0 after navigating to the chat.  It does not.. but if I refresh, it does.   So, clearly, I'm not updating state properly.   Can someone smarter than me tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Oh... and I'm using this as a hook, but I could move this code into the component if needed.  Here's the gist:

```
const useUnreadMessagesCount = () => {
    const { user } = useAuth()
    const { client: chatClient } = useChatContext()
    const [unreadCount, setUnreadCount] = useState<any>()
    const { token } = useStreamToken()

    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            // set state initially because it appers that client.on events only happen a new event.
            if (user != null) {
                const response: any = await chatClient.connectUser({ id: user.uid }, token)
                setUnreadCount(response.me.total_unread_count)
            }

            // update state when a new event occures.
            chatClient.on((event) => {
                console.log("HERE")
                if (event.unread_channels !== undefined) {
                    console.log("COUNT: ", event.total_unread_count)
                    setUnreadCount(event.total_unread_count)
                }
            })
        }

        init()

        // @ts-ignore
        chatClient.on("user.presence.changed", init())

        return () => {
            // @ts-ignore
            chatClient.off("user.presence.changed", init())
        }
    }, [chatClient])

    return unreadCount
}

export default useUnreadMessagesCount
```